# How to set authorization header on background-image: url()?

Tags: javascript, http, reactjs, authorization

I am trying to retrieve background images via a REST API.

However, to do so, I need to authorize.

The token is available from the context where the background-image is supposed to be loaded but I have no idea how to add it to the request.

Any ideas? Is this possible at all?

In another approach I used my webserver to add authorization to all requests from within a certain context. This worked fine but is not possible anymore.

Comment: You can simply pass the token in request header.

Comment: @PiotrSołtysiak, I don't understand how. I am using background-image: url("/service/1234");

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way would be to request the images via Javascript, set the correct headers and then display the images as an object URL/blob. Here's an example:

```js
fetch('https://i.imgur.com/PLKabDV.png', { headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json" // this header is just an example, put your token here
  } })
  .then(response => response.blob())
  .then(blob => {
    let img = document.getElementById('image');
    let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    img.style.backgroundImage = `url(${url})`;
  })
```

```html
<div id="image" style="width: 430px; height: 430px;"></div>
```

Comment: only problem I have with this is the asynchronity (?). Is there a way to do this synchronously?

Comment: What do you want to do? Server requests are asynchronous by design.

Comment: What about when `Content-Type: image/jpeg`?